# One month old puppy pacing in circles and crying

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, veterinarian, puppy

I picked up a stray puppy from the side of the road 3 days back. She is an Indian breed. She was crawling on her belly into shade when I found her.

I picked her (brown) up along with 2 other (black) puppies. The other two black ones are healthy and eating well.

This brown one is not eating or drinking on her own, I need to feed her with a syringe. When she gets up she starts crying and pacing in circles.

I am feeding her glucose and water every other day or so. If I put a few pellets of dog food in her mouth, she is chewing and swallowing. Otherwise she is unresponsive to other sounds or movements, she keeps on pacing and sometimes she keeps blankly staring at something.

The other two pups are responding well, they recognize me and are playful. What could be wrong with the brown one?

PS: All 3 look to be around one month old.

I already took her to a vet, and all she told me was to hydrate her every hour with glucose and water until she becomes healthy and then bring in for diagnosis. The vet didn't even touch the puppy.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If in doupt for the health of your pet, please do not wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet. Instead visit a vet or a shelter to get help foe this puppy! Sadly I am not expert in dogs and have no idea how to help you.

Comment: I already visited a renowned veterinary hospital in my area. They told me to hydrate her every hour or so and get her back to health, then only they can provide some answers. Not very helpful. My usual vets are out of town.

Comment: This is an essential part of you question :) please add it with the "edit" button. What do you mean by "hydrate her every hour", to let her drink?

Comment: Sure, will do. By hydrate her, I meant feed her glucose and water with a syringe into her mouth.

Comment: Please add a short description, what the vet did (for example blood test, or looks onto the eyes, the mouth and so on)

Comment: How sure you are with the age? I read, that puppies around 2-3 weeks starts to defecating by themself, before the mum will lick their lower abdomen to start the process. To gentle massage this area may help. I assume you searched yourself for sources about orphan puppies, and which help is required for which age?

Comment: I have had two dogs previously. the defecating part is working fine. She's pooping and peeing by herself. The other two pups would go outside and do their business, but this one is doing it wherever it wants. Something is wrong with the coordination inside its head I think.

Comment: I know you've said Indian breed. Could you confirm that you're in India? It's relevant because of the relatively high prevalence of rabies in India

Comment: @innisfree If you look at OP's profile, you'll see he lives in Aluva, Kerala, India.

Comment: They are most likely 5 weeks old based on their eating and motion descriptions.

Comment: I had a dog that died of ["distemper"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canine_distemper), he got blindness and moved in circles because of damage of the nervous system (the vet might tell you that he should be put to sleep)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I took her to a good vet today. She checked her, found that she was blind, but she was responding to sounds well. She was pacing in circles when she got stressed. Today with this new knowledge, I brought her home, started training her with sounds. She started responding well, she would circle a bit and then once she recognizes where the sound came from, she would walk in that direction. She even started drinking and eating on her own after she got comfortable with me. I have to hold the food and water up to her mouth, and she would eat/drink it, technically not by herself, but it's a big improvement compared to feeding her with syringe. Thanks for your help guys.

UPDATE- 15-Mar-2021

She is now eating well. No need to hold the container near her mouth anymore. She identifies objects and people, and has become better tuned to focus on sounds and smells. She has become familiar with her surroundings now, and knows where things are at. She is eating more compared to the other two pups now, also she has started play fighting with the other pups. Before she was always confused and unable to fight back. I feel she is on a path to a healthy normal dog life.

Comment: Wow, I cannot tell you how happy I am that it's not rabies, as I feared. My own dog has become blind (he's an old man now) and I can tell you that even blind, dogs can still have a happy life. You should train "stop" with her so you can warn her before she walks into objects.

Comment: Also look into a "Halo for blind dogs" maybe? https://www.google.com/search?q=blind+dog+with+harness

Comment: Vision is important for dogs, but not as important as it is for us. The sense of smell is the most important for dogs; she is still able to perceive all the stimuli that dogs are the most interested in. I hope this information helps you to stay optimistic about your dog if you get worried about her blindness and its negative impact on her quality of life. I wish all the best for you and your dog.

Comment: Wow that was a roller-coster of a post. Glad everything is fine, you should mark your question as solved ;) (it will give people less anxious, like me :|, when reading).

Comment: So... is the first vet completely incompetent? Is there a way to report that? I'm not a vet, but I would expect blindness to be... uh, pretty severe and something that a licensed vet should be able to diagnose.

Comment: @Snifkes: Unfortunately Stackexchange doesn't bring solved posts to the top if the solver is also the original poster.  No idea why.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @Elmy. Sure, I have already started training her to follow my voice. I have bought to small bells to be put on the other two dogs, so she can track the other two eventually. I will also start teaching her stop like you said.

Comment: @MooingDuck. thanks for the info. I'll look that up for sure. Should I wait until she is little more older and strong, right now she is very small, and just started taking food and water on her own.

Comment: @Snifkes. Thanks, I have marked the question as solved.

Comment: @Nelson I had taken her to a big government run hospital because my usual vet was not available, dont know why the vet didnt diagnose, they were telling I should bring her up to health and then they will be able to diagnose. As soon as my regular vet was available, I took the puppy to her and she helped me out with the diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks @lila. I sure hope to give her the best life possible. Its the first time I am dealing with a blind dog, so fingers crossed. But I am optimistic I will be able to take up this personal project.

Comment: So glad to hear she's improving! It's really nice to see a happy resolution to what could have been a very tragic story.

Comment: @AllisonC true, even I was scared for her badly the first few days, but now I am happy

Answer (score 54):

### BEWARE OF RABIES! DANGER TO LIFE

The symptoms you describe, the lack of motor control, the unawareness, staring into nothing, not being able to drink and eat on her own, could all be symptoms of rabies.

**Rabies is 100% lethal to all infected humans and animals that are not vaccinated.** If you're not vaccinated, please get the vaccine for you and your family **as soon as possible**. The rabies vaccine is the only effective treatment and it's still effective after you were infected and before the first symptoms set in. Even if you were vaccinated in the past, let your doctor check that the old vaccine is still effective and refresh it just in case. If this puppy indeed has rabies and infects you, there is no way to save your life as soon as you feel the first symptoms. That will be a fever and/or tingling at the site of infection (usually a bite or other wound).

*(In the recent 10 years there have been several accounts of people surviving rabies. All of them have been only partially vaccinated and all of them retained very severe brain damage or died a few months later. There is no report of someone without any antibodies ever surviving. So even if you "survive" rabies, you won't ever be healthy again.)*

> [Rabies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies) is spread when an infected animal bites or scratches a human or other animal. Saliva from an infected animal can also transmit rabies if the saliva comes into contact with the eyes, mouth, or nose. Globally, dogs are the most common animal involved. In countries where dogs commonly have the disease, more than 99% of rabies cases are the direct result of dog bites.

You must separate the puppy from all other dogs and especially humans and children to avoid even more infections. **Protect yourself from sudden, unforeseeable bites**. The virus replicates in the nervous tisseus, including the brain and spinal cord and is eventually shed in the saliva of infected animals. Rabies is NOT found in the urine or blood of infected animals. You must always wash your hands and all objects that came into contact with the puppy with lots of soap, or better a 70% ethanol or phenol solution (many hand sanitizers are based on ethanol; read the list of ingredients to make sure). Be aware that the disinfectant must be applied for a prolonged time (most often several minutes) to be effective and you must apply more sanitizer to your hands until the required time (read the package leaflet) is over.

Rabies has many non-specific signs in animals that may be hard to detect in the beginning or can be confused with other signs. If the puppy becomes aggressive or has foam or thick saliva on its mouth, it could indicate that it has rabies, however, this can only be confirmed after a post-mortem laboratory test has confirmed the presence of the virus. Unfortunately, if the animal is in fact rabid and clinical signs have manifested, the mortality rate is near 100% and the animal will die from the disease.

Also **keep a watchful eye on the other 2 puppies.** They may be infected as well, but may not show any symptoms yet. If they are infected, they start shedding viruses (read: they could infect humans and other animals) **before** they show the first symptoms. If you can afford the treatment, get them vaccinated against rabies ASAP.

I hope very much that I am wrong with my assumption, but in case this puppy does have rabies, please be extremely careful and don't endanger your own life for the life of an animal you won't be able to save anyways.

There is a global charity (Global Alliance for Rabies Control) that specializes in rabies elimination in all rabies-endemic countries. It offers free online courses to teach you more about the disease and to raise awareness about the disease. You can learn more about rabies and help prevent eliminate the disease globally. Check out there website here: https://rabiesalliance.org

Further reading:

- [How do we deal with or prevent exposures?](https://caninerabiesblueprint.org/5-5-4-How-do-we-deal-with-or?lang=en) by caninerabiesblueprint.org
- [Rabies Virus Fact Sheet](https://ehs.stanford.edu/reference/rabies-virus-fact-sheet) by Stanford University
- [Disinfection protocols for necropsy equipment in rabies laboratories: Safety of personnel and diagnostic outcome](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166093415301233) by FAO and National Reference Centre for Rabies, OIE Collaborating Centre and National Reference Centre for Diseases at the Animal-Human Interface, Istituto Zooprofilattico Sperimentale delle Venezie, Viale dell’Università 10, 35020 Italy

Comment: "Rabies is 100% lethal to all infected humans and animals that are not vaccinated." There's a reason why Old Yeller got shot at the end of the movie, after all. I'd definitely say to take the dog back to the vet for a second opinion if you suspect it might be rabid.

Comment: I would be concerned about possible rabies infections in all 3 puppies, if they were part of the same litter or found together.

Comment: _Put all objects into bright sunlight to kill any remaining viruses_ – If you believe an object has come into contact with a virus, do **not** expect sunlight to completely sterilize it!

Comment: Rabies can also incubate for a long time. This particular puppy may be immune compromised so the virus is destroying the nervous system faster.

Comment: I think I may have possibly heard of a single case of rabies in humans being cured after onset of symptoms. But take that with a grain of salt. It is a very, very scary disease. You can often get vaccinated after being infected, so if you're bitten (especially in an extremity), it's not too late. But don't take any risks.

Comment: @nelson are you saying the other 2 puppies may also be infected but not showing symptoms yet as not immuno-compromised? I know nothing about this possibility, but I would urge extreme caution around all 3 of these dogs

Comment: I think you should add the fact that the OP appears to be in India, where rabies is prevalent, as a factor to take in combination with the dog’s symptoms. I guess the symptoms alone would be less troubling in counties that (to a large degree) eradicated rabies, though possibly still cause for some concern

Comment: @Arthur In the recent 10 years there have been several accounts of people surviving rabies. All of them have been only partially vaccinated (there is no report of someone without any antibodies ever surviving) and all of them retained very severe brain damage or died a few months later. So even if you "survive" rabies, you won't ever be healthy again.

Comment: Unless the veterinarian who examined the pup is beyond incompetent, it's unimaginable that they wouldn't have observed symptoms indicative of rabies .  it's far more likely there's a severe intestinal infection (worms) or other problem.  As they say in the medical world, "If you hear hoofbeats, think horse, not zebra."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, there is a possibility that the puppy doesn't have rabies, but OP wrote that the vet didn't even touch it, so I won't trust any of their diagnoses. And considering the possibility of infecting humans I found it extremely important to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Arthur You may be thinking of [Jeanna Giese](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/jeanna-giese-rabies-survivor/).  She can no longer play sports, but her doctor says she is “pretty much normal.”  Obviously her case is an outlier.

Comment: The fatality rate is not true at all.  This only accounts for people who exhibit symptoms that don't appear until late stages of the disease, often a month or more after exposure.  A study in Peru where vampire bats are common shows that 6 out of 63 test subjects had antibodies to rabies without ever being vaccinated.  And in recent times, treatments have been developed for late stage cases, the first known person to survive a late stage case was in 2004 after medical intervention.